# MongoDB: Node, changing data (write to db) inside each loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I go about changing data (writing data) inside my `.each` loop?

e.g.

```
var q = {}; // some query here

    db.collection('somedata').find(query).each(function(err, doc) {

    if(doc.flag === true) {
        doc.anotherField = true; // change some data here??
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to array using toArray and then you can loop inside .

```
 var q = {}; // some query here

        db.collection('somedata').find(query).toArray(function(err, doc) {
            if(err)throw err;
        doc.forEach(function(eachDoc){
                if(eachDoc.flag === true) {
                eachDoc.anotherField = true; // change some data here??
            }
        });


    });
```